# Python: Practicing A Grocery List - Question regarding

Tags: python

I am looking to ask the user to pick from the items list. I figured I could ask the user a designated amount of questions ("Enter your Items: ") and add all of the questions up (like q1, q2, q3, etc.).

But I would rather allow the user to pick an indefinite amount of items until they hit Enter and break the loop. THEN add all of the prices from their entry, as long as it matches the `fmPrices` dict.

```
import math


dollar = "$"

items = ["Eggs","Milk","Chips","Butter","Grapes","Salsa","Beer"]
items.sort() 

choice = ("Choose from the following items:")
print (choice)
print (items)

fmPrices = {
    "Eggs" : 2.99,
    "Milk": 3.99,
    "Chips": 4.29,
    "Butter": 3.29,
    "Grapes": 3.49,
    "Salsa": 40.99,
    "Beer": 1.99

}

while True:
    q1 = input("Enter your item: ")

    if q1 == '':
        break
    else: 
        input("Enter your item: ")


print ("Your estimated cost is: ")
total = round(fmPrices[q1],2)

print ("{}""{}" .format(dollar, total))
```

Comment: You are asking for the items, but you aren't storing them in a list.  You need to have a lilst of items, and use `grocerylist.append(q1)`.  Also, DO NOT repeat your question.  You'll repeat it when the while loops.  Just delete the `else` and the second `input` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = []
total = 0
while True:
    q1 = input("Enter your item: ")
    if q1 == '':
        break
    if q1 not in fmPrices:
        print("Item is not in the list")
    else:
        mylist.append(q1)
        total += fmPrices[q1]

print ("Your estimated cost is: ")
print( "$", round(total,2) )
```

Comment: Tim! Thank you so much. That solved the issue - also thank you for writing a much simpler, cleaner way to include the "$" sign. I had clearly overcomplicated it. This was very helpful!!

Comment: @Zamdokie Mark questions that helped you solve the problem by clicking the checkbox beside the answer. Do it to your other questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```py
cost = 0

while True:
    q1 = input("Enter your item: ")
    if q1 == '':
        break
    price = fmPrices.get(q1)
    if price == None:
        print("Item not available")
    else:
        cost += price 

total = round(cost,2)
print(f"Your estimated cost is: {dollar}{total}")
```